# Show that the function is positive

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a Lipschitz continuous, monotone increasing function, with $f(0)=0$, if a function $\phi$ satisfies;
>
> $\displaystyle\cases{
> \phi'(t)=f(-\phi(t))-f(\phi(t))  & \cr
> \phi(0)=1 
> }$,
>
> why must be $\phi(t)>0$ $\forall t\in\mathbb R\ ?$

Actually this is not the exercise, only a part of it, which I don't understand, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $G\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R};\; G(u) = f(-u) - f(u)$ is Lipschitz continuous with $G(0) = 0$.

So the solutions to the differential equation

$$y' = G(y)\tag{$\ast$}$$

to a given initial condition are unique by the Picard-Lindelöf theorem. It is easily verified that $\psi(t) = 0$ is a solution of $(\ast)$ for the initial condition $y(t_0) = 0$. Hence any solution of $(\ast)$ that is nonzero at some point $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$ is nonzero on its complete domain of existence [which is $\mathbb{R}$, again by Picard-Lindelöf].

The given $\phi$ is positive at $t_0 = 0$ by the initial condition, it is a solution of $(\ast)$ by assumption, hence it is positive on all of $\mathbb{R}$ by the uniqueness of solutions.

Comment: yes if $y(t_0)=0$ then $y\equiv 0$ is a solution, by Cauchy-Lipschitz it is the solution, but how do you deduce then, that it must be positive on the whole domain, if $t_0>0$, where did you make use of the property of $f$ ?

Comment: The uniqueness says that if a solution has any zero, it must vanish identically. The contrapositive says that a solution that is nonzero at any point is never zero. The intermediate value theorem says that if it attained positive as well as negative values, it would also have at least one zero. Together, positive at any point implies positive everywhere.

Comment: Only the Lipschitz continuity of $f$ is required, since that implies the Lipschitz continuity of $G$.

Comment: Aha I'm enlightened now, so different solutions never cross, thanks a lot.